# How do I avoid out of order inserts using Influx line protocol on QuestDB

Tags: questdb

I am testing IoT sensors which each send temperature readings to a QuestDB instance, I'm using a basic TCP socket connection in Python to send it like the following:

```py
import datetime as dt
import socket
import Adafruit_DHT

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9009

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 23
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def now():
  return int((dt.datetime.utcnow() - dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 1000) * 1000000

while True:
  humidity, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
  if temp is not None:
    try:    
      sock.sendto(('readings,sensor=%s temp=%s %s' % (sensor_name,temp,now())).encode(), (HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as e:
      print("Got error: %s" % (e))

sock.close()
```

This can insert data to a `readings` table, but it looks like some readings are missing and I see

```
cannot insert records out of order
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the timestamp on the client side and allow the server to assign one that's the server's system time. This means you can get rid of calling the now() function in your example:

```py
import socket
import Adafruit_DHT

# maybe an environment variable can identify the IoT device
sensor_name="My sensor"

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9009
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 23

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
  humidity, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
  if temp is not None:
    try:    
      sock.sendto(('readings,sensor=%s temp=%s' % (sensor_name,temp)).encode(), (HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as e:
      print("Got error: %s" % (e))

sock.close()
```